# Is it possible to share the same Objects to all requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to generate a key for my authenticationservice by startup of the application and use it for all requests. So i have to store it somewhere and make it accessible. And I need some other Objects as well be shared for all requests.
In C# there it is possible to make it via static variables, but not in Spring Boot. 
Do you know a way to do this? 
I know a workaround to generate all at startup and put them into the database, but i think thats a dirty way .

I'm new to Spring Boot and appreciate the help.

Comment: in spring, you can create `bean`s and you can inject them where ever required... http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missunderstand what `Springboot` is, it has nothing to do with static scopes.

Since spring embed his own DI framework, you can create injectable beans, and then use them anywhere in other managed-beans. Injectable beans are class that the lifecycle is managed by the DI container, and they can be instantiated differently to suits your need. You might take a look at [Spring bean scope](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).

If you want to have a bean which remains the same for all request you must use scope `Singleton`, which is the default one.

```
// No need to provide the scope, since singleton is the default one
@Component
public MySingletonBean {

    private final String key;

    // Yes, the constructor is private, but spring will see it anyway
    private MySingletonBean() {
        key = generateAKey();
    }

    private String getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }
}
```

With this component (that DI framework know as a singleton) you can use the same key everywhere in your application, and the key will remain the same unless the server restart.

You can use it anywhere with `@Inject`.

**Example using it in controller**

```
@RestController
public void MyController {

    @Inject
    private MySingletonBean mySingletonBean;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        String key = mySingletonBean.getKey();
        return key;
    }
}
```

**DO NOT use the MySingletonBean constructor by your own. IOC framework will take care of bean instantiation**

Comment: Wow thanks! It seems like this is an easy way to do this.

Comment: @Mortalis you're welcome. Mark your question as `answered` [explaination-here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/300659)

Comment: Stupid question, but i dont find the @Inject Annotation in my Spring Boot and dont know the library for it. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @Mortalis You need to include the following dependency :
`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>`
in your pom.xml, if you do not want to, you can use spring's equivalent `@Autowired`, inject and authowired works the same in spring.

Comment: Thank you again, i tried it out. It works! Very nice :).